# MP4 file stored with git lfs not playing in Github Pages

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I have an mp4 file I have in my repository stored with git lfs which I want to be able to play on my website. When I open the site with github pages, the video is not visible.

Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: Any HTML codes? Check Developer Console for HTTP response.

Comment: That's probably because your repository uses "default" deployment workflow or what's the thing, but that one indeed does not support Git LFS, so you'll need to change the deployment procedure to use one of the workflows and enable Git LFS in that workflow's `Checkout` step (*as described [here](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/50337#discussioncomment-5349819)*).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Original answer (2019): You can see workarounds proposed in [git-lfs/git-lfs issue 1342](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1342): "GitHub pages serving the reference file instead of the actual binary"

The [latest one](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1342#issuecomment-467321479) (from Feb. 2019):

> ```
> https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/_Username_/_Project_/_Branch_/_Path_to_file_
> ```
>
> You should replace all the `_UNDERSCORED_` things to your's

Example in this project: [`labcesi-strasbourg/labcesi-strasbourg.github.io` commit c53bd39](https://github.com/labcesi-strasbourg/labcesi-strasbourg.github.io/commit/c53bd3990c87f3ee03fb513d9fec4e4d8ad1a529)

```
vrView.setContent({
    //image: 'V0050069.jpg',
    image: 'https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/labcesi-strasbourg/labcesi-strasbourg.github.io/master/V0050069.jpg',
    //preview:'/url/to/amazing-512.jpg',
    is_stereo: false
});
```

---

Update Oct. 2022: [Marco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376390/marco) suggests this might no longer work, and would use the following version:

https://github.com/labcesi-strasbourg/labcesi-strasbourg.github.io/blob/master/V0050069.jpg?raw=true

In other words:
[https://github.com/\](https://github.com/%5C)<user>/<repository>/blob/<branch>/<path-to-file>?raw=true

> The above format works for every type of media (jpg, webm, etc..)

Comment: I believe that this no longer works.

Comment: @Marco I haven't tested it recently: did you find an alternative which would work?

Comment: https://github.com/labcesi-strasbourg/labcesi-strasbourg.github.io/blob/master/V0050069.jpg?raw=true

Comment: The above format works for every type of media (jpg, webm, etc..)

Comment: @Marco Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.