# How to Get Videos to Load on Github Pages html?

Tags: html, github, github-pages

I'm trying to get a few videos to play on a webpage using Github pages, I've uploaded my video files to my repo but the videos aren't loading when I open the webpage, but they work when I run my .html files locally. Here's a code snippet of what I have:

```
<video width="1280" height="720" controls autoplay muted loop>
<source src="videos/WebIntroG.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I've also tried this:

```
<video width="1280" height="720" controls autoplay muted loop>
<source src="https://michael1410.github.io/RobotGoon/videos/WebIntroG.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Not sure if this matters but my video files are stored with git-lfs, they were over 50MB. Thanks.

Edit: So I've uploaded a smaller video file, under 25 MB, and it worked. So
I'm not sure gitpages will load .mp4 files larger than 50MB stored
using git-lfs.

Comment: Does the rest files like css and js files work properly?

Comment: yep everything else is working

Comment: Can you check your uploaded video? Because your provided url not working. https://michael1410.github.io/RobotGoon/videos/WebIntroG.mp4

Comment: Yeah the link isn't working but I can download the video files from my repo and they work, so the files are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so the solution was posted at [MP4 file stored with git lfs not playing in Github Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56470398/mp4-file-stored-with-git-lfs-not-playing-in-github-pages) by VonC. For .mp4 files stored with git-lfs use this:

```
https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/_Username_/_Project_/_Branch_/_Path_to_file_
```

Edit: Just a heads up, there's a storage and bandwidth limit for git-lfs of
1GB a month and it cost 5$ to buy more (you get 50 GB for 5$).

Answer (score 0):

Along with 'autoplay', 'muted' and 'loop' try adding 'playsinline'. It worked for me.